# How to scrape a table data using php and load that into databse table

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in PHP. I want to **scrape** data from https://www.pmkisan.gov.in/StateDist_Beneficiery.aspx website and load it in database. But here problem is  i want to **scrape** data for particular district only. For that i have to click on that district and main problem is URL is not changing after selecting particular district. Anyone knows solution or is there any solution using laravel?

I tried this

```
$src = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$src->formatOutput = true;
$src->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$content = file_get_contents("https://www.pmkisan.gov.in/StateDist_Beneficiery.aspx");
@$src->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($src);
$values=$xpath->query('//td[ contains (@id, "ContentPlaceHolder1_GrdViwDist") ]');
foreach($values as $value)
{
echo $value->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

but i am getting blank page

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned website uses form submit to display data so you have to click on the link to submit the form and it is handled by javascript. So you have to use http clients to make http requests. DOMDocument class in php is not intended to handle such tasks. DOMDocument is used to parse and modify html or xml doms.